Programmatically added material does not render properly
I am trying to programmatically use one of the Reality Composer Pro's default materials in RealityView. But it's not rendered properly -- all texture is lost.



Expected
Actual









Here is my code:
RealityView { content in
    if let material = try? await ShaderGraphMaterial(named: "/BrownLeather", from: "BrownLeather.usdz", in: realityKitContentBundle) {
        let sphere = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.1), materials: [material])
        content.add(sphere)
    }
}

I can add the material to objects in Reality Composer Pro and directly import the objects into RealityView, that works fine and is rendered correctly. Setting UV_Scale as suggested in this answer doesn't work.

In Reality Composer Pro, you need to apply library material to any primitive shape. After that you'll be able to programmatically load this material from current working scene.
RealityView { content in
    if let matX = try? await ShaderGraphMaterial(named: "/Root/BrownLeather", 
                                                  from: "Scene.usda", 
                                                    in: realityKitContentBundle) {
        let sphere = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.1), 
                            materials: [matX])
        content.add(sphere)
    }
}



According to logic, the MaterialX in the Shader Graph must have some kind of surface to which it is applied (PreviewSurface and Outputs nodes).

Can you elaborate more on the "logic"? Is there a reference link?

The documentation.

Alas, at the moment, you are unlikely to find such details in the documentation.

@JackGuo, perhaps this post will also be interesting to you.
